# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "vaapidecode"

Tags: gstreamer, vaapi

when I run this line

```
gst-launch filesrc location=source.mp4 ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-rgb ! vaapidecode  ! avimux ! filesink location=result-rgb.avi
```

I got this error

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "vaapidecode"

Comment: You'll need to install the GStreamer VAAPI package, which may be a tricky thing to do as it appears your OS is still running GStreamer 0.10.  Post more info on your OS and someone may have some tips for you.

Comment: I have already installled it but the same problem

Comment: Did the library install to /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10?  If it did then you'll probably need to update your GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable before you run gst-launch.

Comment: thank you but  how can I update  GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment ?

Comment: You'll want to read up on environment variables for whatever operating system you're using.